# Add <br> line break from the source file that will get displayed in aspx file

Tags: asp.net, .net, line-breaks

I have a code like the following in my source file:

```
desc = p.Description;
```

I want to add a break to this 'desc' field as follows:

```
desc = p.Description +"<br>"+ moreDesc;
```

This of course doesn't work. I want to use this desc field to write to aspx. Any thoughts on how to introduce 
 into source file?

Comment: Why "This ofcourse doesnt work"? What do you see?

Comment: Is this going in a Literal, a Label or are you printing it somewhere else?

Comment: any time I see content such as `Description` concatenated with html (`<br>`), I'm thinking "ooh, juicy XSS attack surface"

Comment: is "desc" a string?
You may also need to cast p.description to a string, depending on what it is to start with.

Comment: @ Amiram...since <br> is a string it gets displayed like that in UI..@Echilon...im getting this dispalyed in aspx file...@darkcat...desc is a String..s..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the line break is being encoded before it's displayed on the page.  Try [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx):

```
desc = HtmlDecode(p.Description + "<br>" + moreDesc);
```